# chain swiper animation using Gsap

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, gsap

I needed to create an animation like this but the result was not like what I expected, can someone help me, please?

https://www.loom.com/share/1f9c4a135f264b2fae53ba1556a6e88e?sid=692ccf55-7b2e-4735-9680-247604b4c60e

to explain:

I have three images, and I want to make an animation to swipe between the three images,
when the current image goes to disappear the other one comes to the screen

this is my current code:

note: the images will be changed later

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { useGSAP } from '@gsap/react';
import {
  HeroContent,

  ImageSizes,
  Wrapper
} from './Hero.styles';
import Tajine from 'public/assets/images/Tajin.png';
import MyImage from '../MyImage';

const Hero = () => {
  // Refs for images
  const imageRefs = [useRef(), useRef(), useRef()];

  // Animation function
  const animateImages = () => {
    imageRefs.forEach((imageRef, index) => {
      const tl = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1 });

      const moveOut = { x: '300%', y: '150%' };
      const moveCenter = { x: '0%', y: '0%' };
      const moveBottomLeft = { x: '-300%', y: '100%' };

      tl.set(imageRef.current, { ...moveOut, opacity: 0 })
        .to(imageRef.current, {
          opacity: 1,
          duration: 0.5,
          ease: 'power4.out',
          delay: 1.5 * index
        })
        .to(imageRef.current, {
          ...moveCenter,
          duration: 2,
          ease: 'power4.out'
        })
        .to(
          imageRef.current,
          { ...moveBottomLeft, duration: 4, ease: 'power4.out' },
          '-=0.5'
        );

      if (index < imageRefs.length - 1) {
        tl.from(imageRefs[index + 1].current, { ...moveOut }).to(
          imageRefs[index + 1].current,
          {
            opacity: 1,
            duration: 0.5,
            ease: 'power4.out'
          },
          '-=1.5'
        );
      } else {
        tl.to(imageRef.current, { opacity: 0 }, '+=5');
      }

      tl.to(imageRef.current, { opacity: 0 }, '+=0.5').set(imageRef.current, {
        ...moveOut
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    animateImages();
  }, [imageRefs]);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <HeroContent>
        {imageRefs.map((ref, index) => (
          <MyImage
            key={index}
            src={Tajine}
            alt={`tajine-${index}`}
            sizes={ImageSizes}
            forwardedRef={ref}
          />
        ))}
      </HeroContent>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Comment: Can you create a React code sandbox of what you have?